# How do you send tcp/ip requests from a docker container to the host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, openproject

I'm working out how to run openproject with docker. I'm working through [openproject/docker](https://www.openproject.org/docker/).

I've got the docker image running with an external postgres directory.

I'm now working out how to connect to an existing running instance of postgresql.

The command line I'm using looks ok according to the official documentation.

**EDIT**. Added in the missing -p.

```
docker run -p 8082:80 -p 5432:5432 --name openproject_dev -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-
password@localhost:5432/openproject_dev  \
-v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor   \
-v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject   openproject/community:5.0
```

I've ommitted the -d [deamon] flag so I can see any errors.

When the docker container is being created I get

```
-----> You're using an external database. Not initializing a local database cluster.
   /usr/src/app /usr/src/app
   Starting memcached: memcached.
```

Which I expect.
Then I get an error about connecting to the postgresql server which I don't expect.

```
...
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-
4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
```

I'm guessing the script initialising the container is expecting postgres to be running and it's not. How would you make the docker container port forward requests to 5432 to the host machine on the command line?  ... the opposite of docker run -p 5432:5432 ... which exposes 5432 from the docker container to the host.

Comment: -p is missing for second port > docker run -p 8082:80  -p 5432:5432

Comment: I think that would open up port 5432 on the host to a running port of 5432 in the container.

Comment: I already have 5432 running on the host and it's not running in the container

Comment: for open project you want to use the postgree database right? better change the Title of the question bit confusing, remove that port from the command

Comment: docker run -d  -p 8080 -p 20   -e "DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@host/db" openpf/openproject    have to insert the correct user, password, host and db (database name). https://hub.docker.com/r/openpf/openproject/, good practice to run both on container.

Comment: I've made the title clearer https://stackoverflow.com/users/4348824/jinna-balu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong currently

> docker run -p 8082:80 -p 5432:5432 --name openproject_dev -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-password@localhost:5432/openproject_dev  \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor   \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject   openproject/community:5.0

when you used `-p 5432:5432` it means that you expect something to run inside docker on that port and you want your host machine `5432` port to map to `5432` inside docker.

Next if you were able to run that command, even though nothing is listening inside container, then that would imply that the port on your host is available. This means postgress is not listening on `5432` on host also. It may be listening on a socket. You should try to execute below command on host

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1
```

If you are not able to connect on host using this that means the postgres db is bind to a socket file and not to a IP. Now you have few options that you can exercise

**Mount the socket**

> docker run -p 8082:80 -p 5432:5432 --name openproject_dev -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-password@localhost:5432/openproject_dev  \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor   \
>   -v :    \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject   openproject/community:5.0

**Bind on 0.0.0.0 on host**

If you don't want to mount volume then you should change the bind address of psql to `0.0.0.0` and then change your database url to `-e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-password@<YOURMACHINEIP>:5432/openproject_dev`

**Run on host network**

> docker run --net host --name openproject_dev -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret -e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-password@localhost:5432/openproject_dev  \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor   \
>   -v :    \
>   -v /Users/admin/var/lib/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject   openproject/community:5.0

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors. Can you run --net host and -p 8082:80 on the same command?

Comment: No, when you run `--net host` then port that you listen inside will be the port that is used on host. So in your case app will listen on port 80. When you use --net host, you will have to change port inside container to 8082 for it to use that port on host

Comment: Cool and thanks. I'm now getting a better error message :-) PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "10.1.1.63" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Test with those details from host first and then try, you would need to use 127.0.0.1 when running on --net host

Comment: Thanks for that idea ... I'll test from the container as well. psql -h 127.0.0.1 --user openproject openproject_dev
psql (9.6.5)
Type "help" for help.

openproject_dev=>

It works from the host.

Comment: Many thanks Tarun. Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

```
-e DATABASE_URL=postgresql://openproject:openproject-dev-
password@localhost:5432/openproject_dev
```

When you add this url, the container expects postgres to be running on localhost, i.e. in itself.

If you are running postgres on your host machine, you can let the container share the network stack with the host by passing `--network host` in the run command. In that case, localhost will refer to the host machine where postgres is running.

Comment: This feels right and I'm still getting the same errors.